# Copying QFile contents to another QFile, what's the optimal way?

Tags: c++, qt, file, file-io, memory-mapping

I need to copy a `QFile` to another `QFile` in chunks, so I can't use `QFile::copy`. Here's the most primitive implementation:

```
bool CFile::copyChunk(int64_t chunkSize, const QString &destFolder)
{
    if (!_thisFile.isOpen())
    {
        // Initializing - opening files
        _thisFile.setFileName(_absoluteFilePath);
        if (!_thisFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
            return false;

        _destFile.setFileName(destFolder + _thisFileName);
        if (!_destFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
            return false;
    }

    if (chunkSize < (_thisFile.size() - _thisFile.pos()))
    {
        QByteArray data (chunkSize, 0);
        _thisFile.read(data.data(), chunkSize);
        return _destFile.write(data) == chunkSize;
    }
}
```

It's not clear from this fragment, but I only intend to copy a binary file as a whole into another location, just in chunks so I can provide progress callbacks and cancellation facility for large files.

Another idea is to use memory mapping. Should I? If so, then should I only map source file and still use `_destFile.write`, or should I map both and use `memcpy`?

I guess this question isn't really tied to Qt, I think the answer should be general to any file I/O API that supports memory mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, ok, if it must be a memory mapping solution. Here is one:

```
QFile source("/tmp/bla1.bin");
source.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QFile destination("/tmp/bla2.bin");
destination.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
destination.resize(source.size());
uchar *data = destination.map(0,destination.size());
if(!data){
    qDebug() << "Cannot map";
    exit(-1);
}
QByteArray buffer;
int chunksize = 200;
int var = 0;
do{
    var = source.read((char *)(data), chunksize);
    data += var;
}while(var > 0);
destination.unmap(data);
destination.close();
```

This maps only the destination file into memory. I doubt it will make much of a difference to map the source file also. But this is something for concrete measurements, not assumptions.

Another questions is whether you can map your whole file into memory at once. Constantly unmapping and remapping will certainly cost performance. And even if you use Qt. Functions like memory mapping have the tendency to act disturbingly different on different platforms, e.g. the maximum file size you map in to memory might be different.

Comment: There are good technical reasons for `mmap`'ing the _source_ file instead of the target one. That's because doing it that way round, you save a data copy (from the kernel buffer/mapping the `read` first went in to the userspace data buffer provided to the system call). You can also hint to the system to aggressively pre-fetch/readahead via `madvise(MADV_SEQUENTIAL)` (better than letting the system self-discover readahead). And you can avoid unnecessary block-clearing for partial blocks by writing multiples of the pagesize (`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`) - it makes no sense to copy in smaller units.

Comment: @FranH, thanks. I really must experiment a little bit. Fortunately it is easy to change above code to also map the source file. The kernel space -> user space copy overhead sounds plausible. The multiple pagesizes, too, but of course, if this can be taken into account depends on the requirements.

Comment: Wow, my file manager project is 2 years old already?! Anyway, I've finally gotten to testing the performance on Windows I'm mapping both source and destination files, and then copying the data with `memcpy`. Chunk size is 5 MB, or the whole file if the the file is smaller. There's no difference on big files, but mapping yields huge speedup, over 4x, for small files. 4x was for 400 bytes files. Here's the source if someone is interested: https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/file-commander/blob/47d175f614b152ad5853af8a4b4f04d58eba7e1a/file-commander-core/src/cfilesystemobject.cpp#L327

Answer (score 1):

What the optimal method is, lies always a bit in the eye of the beholder. Here is at least one working shorter method:

```
QFile source("/tmp/bla1.bin");
source.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QFile destination("/tmp/bla2.bin");
destination.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QByteArray buffer;
int chunksize = 200; // Whatever chunk size you like
while(!(buffer = source.read(chunksize)).isEmpty()){
    destination.write(buffer);
}
destination.close();
source.close();
```

And memory mapping... I try to stay away from things like that. I am never too sure how platform independent they are.

Comment: Well that's why we use Qt - to not to be bothered with platform-specific stuff. Worst case scenario - we get the same behavior as in your answer, a temporary buffer to emulate memory mapping. Anyway, I'm not sure why you made this an answer as it's the same code I've already written and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It is the same code you wrote? Not exactly. I don't need no "chunkSize < (_thisFile.size() - _thisFile.pos()". But of course, how many totally different implementations of this quite basic task do you expect? I also thought a bit about data streams, but none of the alternative were any 'lighter'.

Comment: Btw... your "I think the answer should be general to any file I/O API that supports memory mapping." was edite in while I was writing this answer. So, sorry.

Comment: Good tip, thanks. But I still think memory mapping is way to go performance-wise.

Answer (score -1):

Use this QFile::map() method:

```
QFile fs("Sourcefile.bin");

fs.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

QFile fd("Destinationfile.bin");

fd.open(QFile::WriteOnly);

fd.write((char*) fs.map(0, fs.size()), fs.size()); //Copies all data

fd.close();
fs.close();
```

Comment: I know how to call `QFile::map`. The question was what's the best way to do it, taking into account that copying is done in **chunks** - which your answer totally ignores. Flagging as "Not an answer".

Comment: @VioletGiraffe flags are not meant to use for incorrect answers

Comment: fd.write((char*) fs.map(iPos, chunksize), chunksize);    Change the fs.size() to your chunksize, it will start copying in chucks without buffering. Add the iPos to move to next chunk.

Comment: @UmNyobe: what is the "Not an answer" flag for, then?

Comment: @Krishna: please read the question again. You're not even trying to answer it.